# Как в PHP ограничить mkdir

Tags: php

Как в PHP сделать чтобы кодом 1 сайт мог создать папку, а второй нет?

К примеру есть сайты `test.com` и `test1.com` лежащие в папках `D:/www/test/` и `D:/www/test1`.

Как сделать что бы сайт `test.com` смог выполнить и`mkdir("D:/www/123/");` и `mkdir("123");` `а test1.com` только второй?

Answer (score 0):

Наверное правильным решением было бы ограничивать по связке `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` или ip `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` если вы пытаетесь внешне зайти.

Comment: это для хостинга, всё идет у меня на компе, у меня белый ip

Comment: А тогда наверное с помощью apacha надо делать https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/711339

Comment: у меня проблема в том, что с локальных папок можно создавать. Т.е. из папки D:/www/test1 можно создать папку D:/www/123

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю для чего это нужно сделать?

Comment: VPS/VDS хостинг

Comment: Вообще это задача не PHP, а окружения. Можно например задать под каким пользователем будет запускаться веб сервер и выдать этому пользователю права на запись только в каталог D:/www/test1 и подкаталоги (не забыть в папку логов сервера и чтение в нужные папки).